# Product editing e-commerce

Tags: php, e-commerce

Hi here is my code https://pastebin.com/WuP4yvuf

this is not being executed

```
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
                {
                    $query = "UPDATE products SET title = '$title', price = '$price', description = '$desc', category = '$cat', image = '$dbpath' WHERE id = '$edit_id'";
                }
                mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

please help me I'm against time

the problem is that the edit won't stay unless you change the image if you delete and re-upload the image it works but that's no the idea

Comment: Don't post links to code off-site. All relevant code needs to be included into the question itself.

Comment: You also say: _"unless you change the image"_. Your update code is only executed if an image is uploaded (you're checking that `$_FILES` isn't empty) so that's per your design, no?